# Check if cart has any grouped product

Tags: magento

In Magento is there any way to check that cart or quote object has grouped product in it
OR 
I can also ask if the item that are added in cart are part of Grouped product.

Is there anyway to test this out through code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this is the best or not but you can use following code :

```
$groupedParentsIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_link')
                   ->getParentIdsByChild(enter id of product in cart here, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_GROUPED);
```

if Id entered by you have parent then the item is part of grouped product.

You can check for each product in your cart.

Comment: No, that will be a bit lengthy process. Not recommended. Well thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item){
    if($item->getProduct()->getTypeId()=="bundle")
        echo "This is a bundle product";
    if($item->getProduct()->getTypeId()=="grouped")
        echo "This is a grouped product";
    if($item->getProduct()->getTypeId()=="configurable")
        echo "This is a configurable product";
    if($item->getProduct()->getTypeId()=="virtual")
        echo "This is a virtual product";
    if($item->getProduct()->getTypeId()=="simple")
        echo "This is a simple product";
    if($item->getProduct()->getTypeId()=="downloadable")
        echo "This is a downloadable product";
    if($item->getProduct()->getTypeId()=="giftcard") //in enterprise
        echo "This is a giftcard product";

}
```

You can also set up an observer to watch checkout_cart_add_product_complete event

Comment: I know for bundled, I need for grouped product.

Answer (score 0):

In Grouped product there are two parts

The parent product

The child products

In cart we can add only the child product. So you have to check that the cart contain any group product using the below code.

```
 Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to find out if the cart contains any grouped product :

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item){
    $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    $ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
    if(isset($ids) && !empty($ids))    
    {
        echo "This is a grouped product";
    }
}
```